# DataTable - prevent value changing event if value not actually changed

Tags: c#, events, datagridview, datatable

I'm using a DataTable to act as a data binding source for a DataGridView. To update the data I loop through updating the DataTable values doing something like

```
....
Rows[rowIndex][columnIndex] = newvalue;
....
```

My assumption** is that this is triggering a DataGridView redraw, even if the value itself hasn't changed, and I want to avoid this.

I also don't want to litter the code with something like this every time I want to set a value

```
....
if(!Rows[rowIndex][columnIndex].Equals(newvalue))
    Rows[rowIndex][columnIndex] = newvalue;
....
```

I could copy/paste a new DataRow implementation using code out of ILSpy (but thats just asking for trouble).

Is there a simpler way to override this behaviour that I'm missing?

---

** I did try to look through the source in ILSpy.

`System.Data.DataRow : public object this[DataColumn column]` looks like it will always trigger a change event, even if the value itself hasn't changed.  I can't find any references to DataTable within DataGridView though, so I'm not 100% certain that this is causing a redraw.

Comment: But you are changing the data (even if it's the same data), how do you expect it _not_ to redraw? Your choices are either to use `if` or to register to the the event and use `e.Handled = true`

Comment: If the problem is the events are causing too many paint requests, then temporarily you can set `table.DefaultView.RowFilter = "1=0"`, and then set it back to the original row filter after.